# Altering Facebook GraphAPI page scrape data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So i'm currently building a single page app, and therefore need to update the meta data after all the data is loaded. (the app is strictly javascript and html, there is little to no backend trying to be lightweight... the whole app is ~50kb)

Unfortunately, after looking into this issue has lead me to the realization that facebook will never see the updated meta during the screen scrape because the js won't run.

However I did realize that when you a request post to https://graph.facebook.com/id=http://sitename it responds with an object in this format:

```
{
   "url": "http://site/",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "site name",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://site/thumb.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "description": "site description",
   "updated_time": "2014-10-18T20:10:29+0000",
   "id": #
}
```

My question is, is there possible to update this object and send it back to facebook with the values you want them to use?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Facebook scraper only reads data and OG-tags set in the header. See: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

So by setting them up correctly in your app Facebook should pick the data up. Keep in mind that the Facebook scraper has a  caching system, which can be (manually) cleared using the Facebook URL linter.

This tool could also be useful for debugging. See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

The data needs to be there 'static' (or put there by server side language) when the page is loaded, since Facebook scraper will not parse Javascript.

Comment: the meta gets updated after the DOM is loaded, and i believe the scrape only reads the static html, so it never sees any of my data. which means using the debugger to refresh the data wouldn't do any good

Comment: I do not think that's possible. The Facebook scraper reads indeed the static data (or put there dynamically) per url and doesn't call Javascript. Could you tell us more on why you need to put it in there by javascript?

Comment: since my app is only 3 pages total, not including the js and stylesheets. (404, homepage, and the data page). i'm using the hash in the url to identify the proper json to load (http://site/data/#id). because of this all of the logic is done client side through the js, meaning the meta can't be updated until after the DOM is loaded, and by then the scraper has already scraped

Comment: I understand, but can't solve your problem. The data needs to be there 'static' when the page is loaded. Maybe figure out a workaround to put the meta data there?

Comment: thank you anyway! the only other way i can think of is using a server sided language, but i was trying to avoid that

Comment: I'll edit my answer to state that the data should be there before the page load and Facebook doesn't read data put there later by Javascript. Let me know how it works out for you!

Comment: Make a bunch of fake URLs for facebook to scrape and then do a javascript redirect to the real place where the user should go after clicking.